# Procedural carbon fiber material

Tags: materials, node-editor

After several failed attempts to create a procedural carbon fiber material, I decided to look around for tutorials, only to find that the majority require the use of textures. The only promising resource seems to point to a dead page, but from the little information I could gather, it seems to have something to do with two texture nodes and a checker node.

I'm not quite sure what to do with this information, so hopefully someone might be able to fill in the blanks as to how I can achieve that weave-like look that carbon fiber has, without the use of textures.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did it fail? Can you post some images of what you achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my base for how I control my carbon fiber material.

This particular result is stylized for the purpose of indicating the primary color's that I change, to get what I want.

[image: My Stylized Result]

---

And Below is my node setup:

---

[image: My Node Setup]

As time allows, I will circle back around on this, and add the text step-by-step to get this node setup for completeness, however lacking this the images should suffice for now.

Comment: Looks very promising. I'll let you know how it goes in a week or two when I get my computer working again.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work quite well. Had to increase the scale on the brick textures for larger items, but other than that, the image alone is quite self explanatory. I'll probably play around with the rest of the node settings at some point as well.